# Appending n elements to an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array and a hash

```
L = []
H = {3=>"a", 2=>"b", 1=>"c"}
```

And so I will iterate over the keys to get the number of times n the element occurs and append that element to an array n times

Result

```
L = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

What's a nice way to write this with inject (or other methods that I often see in ruby code)?

Comment: Just a side note: Hashes don't preserve insertion order prior to Ruby 1.9 (and in general, hash tables are an unordered data structure), so maybe this is not the right data structure for your purpose in the first place :)

Comment: The elements are sortable objects, so I'm thinking I can just make a sort call afterwards if I need order.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to point it out :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
array = hash.flat_map { |k,v| [v]*k }
```

Comment: Aah, `flat_map`, is there anything you *can't* do?

Comment: Nice, never seen `flat_map` before.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: It cannot yet make you a Pina Colada. I think Matz is working on that.

Answer (score 2):

@David's answer is spot-on for your needs. In general, however, you can add an object *o* to an existing array *n* times via one of:

```
# Modify the array in-place, or…
my_array.concat( [o]*n )

# …alternatively create a new modified array
new_array = my_array + [o]*n
```